# Monte carlo - step size; number of steps and number of iterations - correlation with data size

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am not a mathematics person; currently I am using a tool that performs HMC for random sampling from a large matrix and estimate posterior probability.
It works fine when I provide a smaller matrix (data). For instance.
Using a matrix with the dimension (1774, 100); and with the following MC parameters,

```
Stepsize= 100
nsteps = 1000
max iterations = 1000
```

It performs the random sampling fine.

However,if I provide a much larger matrix (say 1774:300) and with the same parameters, it is not able to sample anything. I tried to increase the number of iterations. From a bit reading, it is important to set the leapfrog parameters correct and more importantly smaller for an accurate estimates. Currently the leapfrog size is (0.1).

So my question is,

```
1. is there a correlation between the step size parameters and the size of the matrix
2. if there is a correlation, how can I estimate an optimal setting, giving the size of my matrix.
```

I am so sorry if i do not make sense, as I mentioned I am a novice to this field. Thanks in advance.

M

Comment: Probably you should post this on the math forum instead of here. Your problem is not related to coding...

Comment: You're gonna need to provide more info. Monte Carlo are a general class of algorithms. But it seems you're using it in a more specific context (sampling from a matrix?)

Comment: yes that is correct... it primarily appied in sampling from a matrix. So bascially, there is two matrices (A and B) and first a joint posterior distribution is estimated. Followed by Gibbs sampling. The methods section of the article is also not detail enough.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is the *size* of the matrix per se which is relevant so much as the distribution of the data in the matrix. A larger matrix can have its data distributed in more complicated ways than a smaller matrix. Among other things, with larger data you might need a burn-in period to allow the chain time to reach steady state.

Comment: By the way, somewhat inconsistently I both upvoted this question (since it is well-written and interesting) and voted to close it -- since I think that it is better asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ (which has tags on MCMC and Gibbs)

Comment: thanks for your input, it is interesting